# Where did I go wrong in counting this nested loop?

Tags: algorithms

I have to come up with two formulas: one for counting the inner-most loop as a function of n and one for counting the middle loop also as a function of n, and from there, state the order of each level. Finally, I have to implement the pseudocode in an actual program to demonstrate the correctness of the formulas.

The pseudocode is as follows:

```
ret:=0
for i:=1 to n do
  for j:=1 to i do
    for k:=j to i+j do
      ret:=ret+1

return ret
```

Now, I think the inner-most loop can be symbolically written as:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} \sum_{k=j}^{i+j} 1$$ which equals to:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} i+1$$ which further simplifies to:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 + i$$ which equals

$$\frac{n^3+3n^2+2n}{3}$$ or $$\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$$

The middle loop, I think, is simply
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} 1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}i = \frac{n^2+n}{2}$$

And my actual code in C++11 is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    unsigned int i_count, j_count, k_count;
    i_count = j_count = k_count = 0;

    // Get 'n' from parameter
    unsigned int n = stoi( argv[1] );

    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        ++i_count;
        cout << "i = " << i << "\n";
        for( unsigned int j = 0; j <= i; ++j ) {
            ++j_count;
            cout << "\tj = " << j << "\n";
            for( unsigned int k = j; k <= (i + j); ++k ) {
                ++k_count;
                cout << "\t\tk = " << k
                     << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\ni_count: " << i_count
         << "\nj_count: " << j_count
         << "\nk_count: " << k_count
         << endl;
}
```

Some output of the above program for various values of `n`:

```
n: 2
i_count: 2
j_count: 3
k_count: 5

n: 3
i_count: 3
j_count: 6
k_count: 14

n: 6
i_count: 6
j_count: 21
k_count: 91
```

As you can see, the `k_count` values don't match the formula $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$. So where did I go wrong? Are the formulas correct?

Comment: When you're doing `for( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i )` , aren't you summing from $i=0$ to $n-1$ rather than from $i=1$ to $n$?

Comment: $\sum_{j=1}^i (i+1) =  \frac{i^2+3i}{2}$, which does not agree with your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to your pseudocode, your deduction of the formulas is correct.

For levels 1, 2, 3, the formulas are $n$, $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$, $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$, respectively.

Your implementation is not quite correct because counting in C++ is $0-based$ which is a bit tricky if you are not used to it.

The problem is, as you might have suspected, rely within level 3.

```
for( unsigned int k = j; k <= (i + j); ++k )
```

You can easily see that this runs $i + j  -  j = i$ times which is obviously incorrect as indicated in your first step of the formula's deduction.

So all you need is to $+1$ ;)

```
for( unsigned int k = j; k <= (i + j + 1); ++k )
```

Yet, as mentioned by [Misha Lavrov](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/383078/misha-lavrov), even though that will evaluate to the correct answer, it would correspond to the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^i \sum_{k=j}^{i+j+1}1$$

Which is equal to the given sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} \sum_{k=j}^{i+j} 1$$

So in case the values i, j, and k mattered in the loop, that solution would be wrong and a more faithful implementation would be as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

typedef unsigned int UINT;

int main() {
    UINT ret = 0;
    UINT i_c = 0, j_c = 0, k_c = 0;

    UINT n = 6;
    for (UINT i = 1; i <= n; ++i, ++i_c) {
        for (UINT j = 1; j <= i; ++j, ++j_c) {
            for (UINT k = j; k <= (i + j); ++k, ++k_c) {
                ++ret;
            }
        }
    }

    cout    << "ret: " << ret << '\n'
            << "i_c: " << i_c << " matches " << n << '\n'
            << "j_c: " << j_c << " matches " << (n * n + n) / 2 <<  '\n'
            << "k_c: " << k_c << " matches " << n * (n + 1) * (n + 2) / 3 << endl;
}
```

Sorry for the long answer, I tried to be as detailed as possible.

Hope I helped.

Comment: That is a loop that works out to the correct answer, but I think you're fixing it in the wrong way. It corresponds to the sum $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^i \sum_{k=j}^{i+j+1}1$$ which is *equal* to the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} \sum_{k=j}^{i+j} 1$$ but the more faithful way to represent the latter would be to actually change the `i` loop to `i=1; i <= n` and the `j` loop to `j=1; j <= i` and leave the `k` loop at `k=j; k <= (i+j)`. If the exact values of `i`, `j`, and `k` mattered in the loop, your solution would be wrong.

Comment: You are right, indeed this is the most obvious way to approach it, but he seemed to have wanted to follow the problem on a 0-based counting methodology if you read his code, so I kinda of fixed his to evaluate a correct answer as well as showing what was the problem with it.

Comment: Nevertheless, I will add your logic to the answer for completeness.

Comment: Ah.. rookie mistake in the implementation. Thanks.